# How can I configure JBoss in Intellij that bind address is not localhost but my IP?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss

In Eclipse you can set hostname for JBoss Runtime. But I can't find this configuration in IDEA Intellij.

netstat -lnt

show

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Intellij > Run > Edit Configurations
2. Select your JBoss Configuration
3. Startup/Connection > Startup Script (Select your run mode Run / Debug / Coverage )
4. uncheck "use default"
5. $JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh -c default -b 0.0.0.0

"-b 0.0.0.0" bound JBoss on any interface.

Answer (score 11):

You could also simply do this in IntelliJ:

1. Select `Run` > `Edit Configurations` from the IDE's menu
2. Select your JBoss as `Application server`
3. Add `-Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0` to your`VM Options`